# docker error when trying to share a volume with host

Tags: docker

I have a very simple docker that is build with the following dockerfile:

```
ADD dependencies /app/dependencies/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/dependencies/SQLAlchemy-1.3.5
RUN python3 setup.py install

WORKDIR /app
RUN python3 setup.py install
ENV NAME World


CMD ["python3", "rock_paper_scissor/run_game.py", "-d", "-dbf", "/scores", "-aip", "3", "-w13"]
```

I build it as :
`docker build  --tag=rockpaperscissor .`

and run it as:

`docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $PWD:/home -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd rockpaperscissor -v /home/lpuggini/Desktop:/scores --name run_game`

but I get this error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Do you know how I can fix?  The error is due to the shared folder.

Answer (score 3):

The sequence in your `docker run` command is causing the problem.

Your `docker run` command should be

```
docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $PWD:/home -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY --device /dev/snd -v /home/lpuggini/Desktop:/scores --name run_game rockpaperscissor
```

Any thing after the image-name (rockpaperscissor in this case) is considered as the command to be executed inside docker container. That's why you get the error `\"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Hope this helps.